# Strategy for safe spoke removal

Tags: wheels, spokes

Let's say someone had a heavy, overly strong front wheel on their re-purposed mtb. 26" wheel, 36 spokes.

What would be a safe pattern to follow to remove between 6 and 12 spokes?

Comment: Do you wish to save the spokes?

Comment: Are you trying to destroy the wheel or just weaken it but keep it rideable?

Comment: What you propose doing is pointless (unless your point is to cause the wheel to fail).

Comment: Can you expand on the underlying intention?  A strong wheel sounds awesome,

Comment: @Criggie Destroying the spokes is fine. The goal is making the wheel lighter.

Comment: How much weight do you think you'd be saving?

Comment: In terms of mechanics, if it's a radially spoked wheel then you could remove every Nth spoke on each side without terribly upsetting the applecart.  However, if it's diagonally laced then anything you do will throw things out of whack.

Comment: A spoke+nipple is about 5-10 grams. Your body weight will vary far more over the course of a day than the amount you save by doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To weaken the wheel you really want to remove a multiple of 4 spokes, so you balance leading, trailing, left and right. Six would be tricky. If the rim is reasonably strong you should be able to remove 12 as 3 groups of four to give that Shimano-style gapped spoke pattern. You'll have a gap, obviously, but the wheel will still be somewhat evenly tensioned.

Ideally you'd rebuild the wheel with the missing spokes distributed as a missing pair from every 6 spoke positions, but that would probably be more work than you want to do. If the wheel isn't fairly new the chance of stuck spokes is high, and disturbing it makes it more likely you'll damage something.

If you're reasonably familiar with truing wheels I suggest backing everything off a turn, removing the spokes, then tightening it all up again. That will let you work the spokes into a reasonably even tension while keeping the wheel straight. Removing groups of spokes when everything is tight will cause odd stressing mid-process and the risk of pulling a nipple through the rim or taco'ing are higher.

But... you're only going to save 20-30 grams, when a lighter wheel will save more. I'd stick with the strong wheel and save/scrounge a light one.

Also, per the comments from Criggie and Daniel R Hicks, if you are cutting spokes remember that they are under tension and the cut parts can exit the wheel with some force. If you want to keep the wheel it's better to back the spokes off rather than cutting them when tight.

Comment: Not to forget the open holes in the rim that you need to close with tape or else, unless you want dirt and water to enter the (probably) hollow rim.

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER**  If you're not saving the spoke, just cut each spoke-to-remove in the middle and remove each half like you would a broken spoke (means removing the tube/tyre)

You should do alternate left-right spokes, rather than several on one side.

You should also keep trailing and leading spokes balanced by taking out pairs/quads of spokes, being a left+right and a leading/trailing set, which will be 4 in a row on the rim of a standard cross-3 pattern.

**NOTE** the nipple and a piece of spoke will probably fly straight out like an arrow and could do someone an injury had they been in the way.  If the tube was in the way it might be a puncture.  The hub end of spoke will likely be held by the other spokes nearby.

The question remains - whether removing spokes is a good idea or not.  You might benefit more from lighter tyres/tubes instead.

Comment: Yep, I did that today, with a spoke that was too long and had gotten jammed into the nipple.  As you experienced, one end of the spoke shot out of the rim.  It only went a few feet before it hit a rather substantial wooden box, so I have no idea how far it could have flown.  But it made quite a ***bang*** when it went.